# Getting intermittent write error while extracting files from zip archive

Tags: python, zip

I have a small application that I have made.  It basically copies a zip file from a network location to the computer that is running the application, unzips it in a folder and then creates a shortcut on the desktop.

Most of the time (I'd say about 80%) it works as intended.  The other 20% of the time the stack trace it says it cannot create a file.  It is always the same (`_bz2.pyd`).  If I close it and run it again it works fine after this happens.

Anyone have any ideas of what is going on?  Here is the code that extracts the file.  I've even made the script try and extract the file, check if it worked, try and extract the file again.  This hasn't solved the issue:

```
print ('uncompressing databases.  This takes a few minutes')
# file_name = settings.working_folder + r'\UAT_Databases.zip'
temp_name = settings_dict['working_folder'] + settings_dict['file_name']
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(temp_name, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall(settings_dict['install_folder'])
zip_ref.close()
logr.info('unzipped databases')
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp_installer.py", line 141, in unzip_databases
  File "zipfile.py", line 1347, in extractall
  File "zipfile.py", line 1335, in extract
  File "zipfile.py", line 1398, in _extract_member
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\TempApps\\Temp_application\\_bz2.pyd'
2020-03-03 11:36:25,697 : ERROR : __main__ : could not unzip databases
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp_installer.py", line 141, in unzip_databases
  File "zipfile.py", line 1347, in extractall
  File "zipfile.py", line 1335, in extract
  File "zipfile.py", line 1398, in _extract_member
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\TempApps\\Temp_application\\_bz2.pyd'
```

Comment: Try to run same script from Admin CMD. That might solve the issue.?

Comment: is it possible that in the 20% of the time when it fails a different process/application has this `_bz2.pyd` file opened/locked, thus the permission error on your script?

Comment: Are there other .pyd, .exe or .dll files in the zip archive?

Comment: @Michael Butscher - There are both .exe and .pyd files in the zip file that is being extracted.   Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Pedro - It is just unzipping the file, if something else is accessing it, it is being done by zipfile

Comment: Two things come to mind: I wonder if you could get `errno 13` in case of concurrent access, IRC Windows can be a but finicky in that regard. Also `.pyd` file is essentially executable code, could it be (perhaps in combination with the former) an antivirus on your host getting involved?

Comment: @user3761017 I was, like Ondrej, thinking about a virus scanner. I would assume that it would interfere with other executables as well but maybe the particular file is the first executable unpacked and the scanner either interferes with this one or none at all for some reason.